# Error validation with Material UI Autcomplete & React hook form

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm building a form using Material UI and using react hook form for validation. It works perfectly using react hook form's Controller component except for Autocomplete. While it captures the Autocomplete data, the error handling doesn't work. I'm assuming it's because while the error object is passed down from the Controller => Autocomplete, it isn't passed down to the nested TextField component. It doesn't work if I do the error validation on the Autocomplete component instead either. Anyone has solved this? My component code is below

```
<Controller
                            name="categories"
                            control={control}
                            defaultValue=''                            
                            render={(props) => 
                                <Autocomplete
                                    className='formInputs'
                                    options={categories}
                                    renderInput={params => 
                                        <TextField
                                            name='autoCompleteTextField'
                                            {...params}
                                            // value={props.field.value}
                                            label="What do you do?"
                                            variant="outlined"
                                            rules={{
                                                required: {
                                                    value: true,
                                                    message: "Please tell us what you're an expert on. It helps us prioritize your referrals"
                                                }
                                            }}
                                            error={Boolean(props.fieldState.error)}
                                            onChange={(e, data) => props.field.onChange(data)}
                                            {...props}
                                        />
                                    }
                                />
                            }
                        />
```

Comment: Which react-hook-form & MUI version are you using?

Answer (score 11):

You're supposed to spread the props of the render callback to the `Autocomplete` component, not the `TextField`. Have a look at the official [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-v7-controller-5h1q5?file=/src/MuiAutoComplete.js). Also, the rules props should be put in the [`Controller`](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller) component.

```
<Controller
  name="country"
  control={control}
  rules={{
    required: "Please enter something"
  }}
```

In order to display the error message from `react-hook-form`, you need to set the [`helperText`](https://mui.com/components/text-fields/#validation) prop of the `TextField`

```
renderInput={(params) => (
  <TextField
    {...params}
    label="Choose a country"
    variant="outlined"
    error={!!fieldState.error}
    helperText={fieldState.error?.message}
  />
)}
```

### Full example

```
<Controller
  name="country"
  control={control}
  rules={{
    required: "Please enter something"
  }}
  render={({ field, fieldState }) => {
    return (
      <Autocomplete
        {...field}
        options={countries}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}
        renderOption={(option) => (
          <span>
            {countryToFlag(option.code)}
            {option.label}
          </span>
        )}
        renderInput={(params) => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            label="Choose a country"
            variant="outlined"
            error={!!fieldState.error}
            helperText={fieldState.error?.message}
          />
        )}
        onChange={(_, data) => field.onChange(data)}
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

You have made two mistakes

1. As @NearHuscarl has said, you should spread `props` in the `<Autocomplete />` component, not in the `<TextField />`
2. Either way if you want to spread `props` into `<TextField />`, you should do it at the beginning, the other way `{...props}` is going to replace the other props that you have defined above the `spread`